# Is it possible to keep docker current, together with its dependencies?

Tags: debian, package-management, docker

I am planning to use Debian as the platform for my docker services, which represent 99% of the activity on this server. I am therefore interested to have a minimal distribution and a stable one.

Except for docker - that one I would like to be updated to its upstream level (more or less).

Is there a reasonable (= sensible, acceptable, ...) way to pin a single package to a "fresher" repository **in a way that would also update the dependencies**?

I am not sure if I should be worried about the emphasized part, it is just that I assume that if I only request the new version for docker, requirements for newer dependencies may not be honored (because the system would not know where to find them)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep Docker updated to track something close to its upstream level, your best bet is to [install the upstream engine](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/). If you follow the instructions there, you’ll end up with an additional repository, based on either Debian 11 or 12 (depending on which version of Debian you are using), with up-to-date Docker packages. This includes all the programs in the Docker ecosystem. As far as other dependencies go, the Docker engine and other components are built statically, with whichever libraries are specified by the builders; so there won’t be any issue with older versions on your chosen platform. (In any case, since Docker officially support Debian 11 and 12, the packages they provide should work correctly there.)

[The Debian Docker package](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/docker.io) provides an older version, and since Docker is quite a difficult package to maintain, I wouldn’t venture to guess how long you’d have to wait for an updated package. (I use the Debian package myself but that’s me.)